# Having API 7 installed makes eclipse unable to build any android code at all

Tags: android, eclipse

Edit: skip to the end, most of this is irrelevant now unless you want to know the history of problem discovery.

I created a new android app in eclipse, pushed it to github, cloned it on another machine, and finally imported it into eclipse there.

The project didn't build at that point, and there were two readily apparent problems:

- An error on the console saying I need to run "Android Tools / Fix Project Properties"
- All my @Override directives didn't recognize the superclass methods and were causing errors.

I fixed the first by running the specified tools which seemed to work. After working around the second by commenting the @Override lines out, nothing is built. Cleaning and rebuilding produces `gen/*/R.java` as it should, and creates the `bin/res` folder, but no `.class` or other files are produced, and no errors are in evidence either. Any ideas?

Edit: It appears that as the commenters suspected, the build environments are just both totally hosed. Nothing builds at all anymore, even newly-created android projects. Turning on verbose build logging shows this near the end:

```
[2011-12-07 19:59:43 - wut]     (new resource id ic_launcher from C:\Users\jorenko\workspace\wut\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png)
[2011-12-07 19:59:43 - wut]     (new resource id ic_launcher from C:\Users\jorenko\workspace\wut\res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png)
[2011-12-07 19:59:43 - wut]     (new resource id ic_launcher from C:\Users\jorenko\workspace\wut\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png)
[2011-12-07 19:59:43 - wut]     (new resource id main from C:\Users\jorenko\workspace\wut\res\layout\main.xml)
[2011-12-07 19:59:43 - wut]   Writing symbols for class R.
[2011-12-07 19:59:44 - wut] Starting full Package build.
[2011-12-07 19:59:44 - wut] Skipping over Post Compiler.
```

WutActivity is never built, and it appears it never even tries to build it.

Edit:

I uninstalled my android SDK, downloaded a fresh copy of both it and eclipse, installed them both with all defaults, created a new Android Sample Project of the Hello World, and I still have the same problem. Next step: nuke computer from orbit?

Edit:

I installed the SDK and eclipse onto a new computer from scratch. It built an example program OK. Then I checked out my app (and installed API7, which my app is built against). Now nothing builds again. Trying this on a new computer with just API7 now.

Edit:

Steps to reproduce:

- Install eclipse and SDK from scratch with all default settings. Install only android SDK tools and API 14.
- Create a sample project and confirm that it builds properly.
- Install API 7.
- Clean your workspace and note that the sample project fails to build as noted above.

The problem continues to persist even after removing API 7. I believe this is a bug introduced in a recent update to the SDK.

Comment: Do you have the same Android/JDK on the two machines?

Comment: I do - they were both installed at the same time. And in fact I see the same problem if I clone into a new a new workspace on the original machine.

Comment: It sounds like the project/environment target is off. Do a diff on the working and the non-working. If they are the same, it still may be a machine/user setting configuration *outside* of the project settings (e.g. repo) -- and git can be removed from being a culprit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After significantly more futzing around, it seems like this can be fixed by a combination of:
 - Turn off verbose build output (there is a bug in the SDK)
 - Turn off waiting on final binaries until launching app